# A function that calculates the number of lines of code is computable?

Tags: computability

How to prove that a function that accepts any argument and outputs the number of lines of code in its program is computable on Unlimited Register Machines. It seems like one should use the recursion theorem, but I don't quite understand how. Or maybe can somehow count the number of configurations.
The URM commands are as follows:

1. Zeroing the nth register
   Z(n)       Rn:=0
2. Increases the contents of the nth register by 1.
   S(n)        Rn: = Rn +1
3. Copying the contents of the register
   T(m,n)     Rn: = Rm
   The contents of the register m, remain unchanged.
4. a conditional 
   J(m, n. p) Rm: = Rn to p
   If there is no command with the number p, the machine stops.
   The remaining URM-computable ones are expressed through them using compositional and primitive recursion

Comment: What do you mean accepts any arguments? and what program? itself?

Comment: The program argument is any natural number. Need to count the number of lines of the program itself.

Comment: What is the context? You need to tell us what definitions you are using.

Comment: added a definition URM

Comment: Presumably the argument is a number that gives the code of a program under some encoding scheme. To answer the question you will need to know what that encoding scheme is. (The answer will then be a deeply tedious URM program that picks apart the program encoded by the argument.) I would hope you have some facts proved in your course that you can use to help with this.

Comment: Why do you need to encode it ? The argument is not related to the program.

Comment: Wait. If I understand correctly, the given function should output the number of lines of its own program? But then it implicitly assumes there's a program for it, so computable.

Comment: so it is, but how to count the number of rows in it?